# Can I use a UserControl from the same project without making a DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-controls, visual-studio-2005

I made a User Control and already was able to use it by adding it to a form in the C# code. The User Control is in the same VS2005 Project as the main form.

The problem is that I can't see the User Control in the gui editor ([Design] window) with this implementation. I tried many things but I wasn't able to add the user control to the real form desing.

I read some things about making a control lib dll and then add this dll to the toolbox but I don't want to have an additional project and an additional binary file.

How can I use a User Control in an form Design, if both are in the same VS Project? I think somehow this should be possible?

Edit 1:

Sorry I have Visual Studio 2005 not 2010

Comment: The answer is no, you don't need to add it to a second project and include it in a DLL.  This happened to me once in VS2005.  My control classes weren't appearing in the toolbox after building the project.  Problem is... I don't remember exactly how I solved it.

Comment: have you tried right clicking on the toolbox and selecting "Choose Items"?

Comment: yes... but problem solved... was a wrong visual studio setting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's certainly possible to use a `UserControl` in design mode when it's part of the same project.

Do note, however, that it will only show up in your toolbox if you have enabled the "AutoToolboxPopulate" setting. Go to the "Tools" menu and select "Options". Expand "Windows Forms Designer", and click on "General". Make sure that the "AutoToolboxPopulate" property is set to True. When you rebuild your solution, your `UserControl` should show up at the top of your toolbox, ready to add to your form.

Alternatively, you can add the `UserControl` to your toolbox manually. To do that, right-click on your toolbox and select "Choose Items" from the context menu. Navigate to your control, ensure that it is checked in the list, and click "OK".

In the event that an exception is thrown (like MacX mentioned), you will still be notified by the designer. The control will still show up in the toolbox, and you'll still be able to attempt to add it to your form.

Answer (score 1):

As APShredder already mentioned the control should automatically appear in the toolbox. If it doesn't check your Visual Studio Settings:

> Tools - Options - Windows Forms Designer - General - AutoToolboxPopulate - True

For further informations just read the [Walkthrough in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw694kde.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a custom User Control in the Winforms designer. You have to build your project first however. You can do this by going to Build --> Build Solution or by pressing F6. Then your control should appear in the Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the toolbox, right-click and choose "Choose items...". Then navigate to the ".NET Framework Components" - your controls should be listed in there. Just choose to add them.

Comment: hmmm isn't listed in here. even after recompile.

Comment: ...not sure then, I have had the same issue and it has worked for me...Glad you got sorted anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no Problem with the Control, except you have an exception which is thrown within the constructor or the Load-Event. The the Designer is not able to display the control correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 after you create a User Control and compiled it, VS add automatically your component and make it visibile in his namespace on ToolBar.
This can be done in Both WPF and old style code/Components...